# ABCpdf nuget package XULRunner folder is corrupt?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xulrunner, gecko, abcpdf

I'm trying to update my (previously working) pdf-creating web application to use the ABCpdf.NET and ABCpdf.NET Gecko Runtime nuget packages.

I've installed both packages (both are version 8.1.1.6) however when I run my application, I get the following **WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Internal.PDFException**:

> Failed to add HTML: Gecko engine hit an error it was unable to recover
>   from. Possible causes: XULRunner folder is corrupt or is from another
>   version of ABCpdf.

After installing the  ABCpdf.NET Gecko Runtime package, I got a dialog telling me that I would need to manually copy the XULRunner folder into my output directory. In order to achieve this, I added the following to my applications .csproj file:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <CallTarget Targets="CopyAbcpdfToDeployFolder" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="CopyAbcpdfToDeployFolder">
    <ItemGroup>
      <SourceDir Include="$(ProjectDir)XULRunner\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceDir)" DestinationFolder="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\$(OutputPath)%(SourceDir.RecursiveDir)\XULRunner" />
  </Target>
```

(This seems to be working correctly - the XULRunner folder and its contents are present in my bin folder after a build)

The line of code that is failing is as follows:

```
theDoc.AddImageUrl(url);
```

Can anyone help me get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, my changes to the `.csproj` file we not copying all files into the correct subfolders. In order to copy the folder structure and files recursively, the XML should have looked like this:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <CallTarget Targets="CopyXULRunnerToDeployFolder" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="CopyXULRunnerToDeployFolder">
      <ItemGroup>
          <MyFiles Include="XULRunner\**\*.*" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy SourceFiles="@(MyFiles)"  DestinationFiles="@(MyFiles->'$(OutputPath)\XULRunner\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish the same outcome with the following MSBuild xml:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="XULRunner\**\*.*">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

I fell upon this setup after dealing with issues concerning the building of a package via MSDeploy not including the XULRunner files.

Not sure if there's anything patently wrong with this, but so far it works for me on a multiple staged deployment setup.