# How do I deploy XULRunner folder to output directory after installing abcpdf gecko via nuget?

Tags: nuget, xulrunner, abcpdf

I installed the ABCpdf.ABCGecko package via nuget, and it gave me this dialog:

> Finished!  Please deploy the XULRunner folder to your output directory manually.

I don't really know wtf this means... I have an idea, but don't know precisely where or how to modify my build configuration to allow this to occur.  Has anyone done this, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My original attempted answer worked fine for my development setup, but didn't work on our staged deployment setup, as for some reason it didn't include the XULRunner files inside the web package created using MSDeploy.  I've found what seems to be a simpler setup, below:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="XULRunner\**\*.*">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

I'm not 100% sure if this works universally, but it seems to work better in every development and deployment scheme I've encountered thus far.

Comment: The XULRunner folder has a different name for different versions. So the folder that goes with ABCpdf 9.1 (based on Firefox 21) is XULRunner21_0. This needs to be factored into any upgrade.

Comment: This worked for me after changing to XULRunner21_0, which appears to be the version in AbcPDF 10 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found how to accomplish this via [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11772578/437456).  The relevant changes to the project's `.csproj` file are below:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <CallTarget Targets="CopyXULRunnerToDeployFolder" />
</Target>
<Target Name="CopyXULRunnerToDeployFolder">
    <ItemGroup>
        <MyFiles Include="XULRunner\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy SourceFiles="@(MyFiles)"  DestinationFiles="@(MyFiles->'$(OutputPath)\XULRunner\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
</Target>
```