# "ErrorMessage":"Failed to find ABCGeckoWP.exe."

Tags: asp.net, abcpdf

I have been beating my head for the last 7 hours on this.  Full disclosure, I am a PHP guy and not the strongest at ASP.net.  So I am coming to you experts.

The issue is that when we run the code below it will product a valid PDF if we use the MSHtmlEngine function (which sets EngineType to MSHtml), but it won't work with the GeckoEngineOptions (which sets EngineType to Gekco).  The problem is that the MSHtml won't generate the SVG graphics, so we need to run the Gecko method.  When we run the Gecko method, it produces this error:

> "ErrorMessage":"Failed to find ABCGeckoWP.exe."

However the file is in the output directory ("bin/"), as well as the project directory.  The XULRunner38_0 also appears to be right as well in both the project and bin/.

I am including some screenshots in case it helps / show what has already been tried (sorry for the sizes being all over the place).

[image: Initial Call]

[image: Master Class]

[image: In Project]

[image: In bin/ After Build]

Comment: It looks like you are using a very old version of ABCpdf, the latest version uses the ABCChrome engine by default which easily handles SVG.

Comment: Yeah.  I agree.  I got pulled into this four days ago trying to get them back online and then coming up with a better long term plan.  Still Gecko (Mozilla) should work.  Unfortunately, I don't have the Chrome option unless they upgrade, but since it isn't their long term resolution, I don't really want to upgrade if we don't have to.

Comment: Try reinstalling the Nuget package for the version that you have a licence for. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077650/how-do-i-deploy-xulrunner-folder-to-output-directory-after-installing-abcpdf-gec

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reinstall  Abcpdf, from Nuget or reinstall the correct version on the server depending on how it's set up.

ABCGecko cannot function without the XULRunner38_0 folder in the same directory as ABCGeckoWP.exe.

On x64 Windows, even if ABCGeckoWP.exe is found only in %SystemRoot%\System32 (though it should be placed only in %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64 for being 32-bit), it never looks up XULRunner38_0 folder in %SystemRoot%\System32 (but in %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64) because of File System Redirection.

So maybe check the file location as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

This error looks like the version of ABCPdf that you are using and the version installed on the server are not the same.

I would also recommend upgrading the version to the latest one and using the Chrome render engine.